# CommerceWishlist class getWishlistSummaries wont take a wishlist ID

Tags: connect-api

I am trying to get the product information for wishlist items.  When I try to use the commercewishlist getWishlistSummaries with the optional wishlist ID i get this error.  I see in the docs that this is a valid method call so why is this error happening
"message": "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getWishlistSummaries(String, String, NULL, Boolean)

Comment: I also Tried getWishlist and that method doesnt exist either?  are the connectApi docs up to date?  did they remove methods for some reason?

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_CommerceWishlist_static_methods.htm), I can indeed not find a method getWishlistSummaries() with 4 parameters. Should you not want to add or remove some parameters?